# Spring DI - do not initialise all the dependent beans

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I have a ServiceA which has a dependency on ServiceB. The serviceB comes from a spring bean file with lazy-init=true i.e, I only want serviceB to be initialised when and if I ask for that bean.

However I do use ServiceA throughout my application and when we do a setter based injection ServiceB gets initialised.

I want ServiceA to not initialise ServiceB *until* any method in ServiceA is called that needs ServiceB. One way of doing this was using the Aspects **but I was looking at the simplest possible solution** for this particularly in the Spring XML file for serviceB or some annotation in serviceB or any proxy flag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a spring lazy proxy factory in Spring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391168/is-there-a-spring-lazy-proxy-factory-in-spring)

Comment: what about passing a ServiceB factory into ServiceA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [`LazyInitTargetSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/target/LazyInitTargetSource.html) does what you need.

> Useful when a proxy reference is needed on initialization but **the actual target object should not be initialized until first use**. When the target bean is defined in an ApplicationContext (or a BeanFactory that is eagerly pre-instantiating singleton beans) it must be marked as "lazy-init" too, else it will be instantiated by said ApplicationContext (or BeanFactory) on startup.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that you might want to try is discussed at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/framework/autoproxy/target/LazyInitTargetSourceCreator.html:

> [LazyInitTargetSourceCreator is a] TargetSourceCreator that enforces a LazyInitTargetSource for each bean
>   that is defined as "lazy-init". This will lead to a proxy created for
>   each of those beans, allowing to fetch a reference to such a bean
>   without actually initialized the target bean instance.
>
> To be registered as custom TargetSourceCreator for an auto-proxy
>   creator, in combination with custom interceptors for specific beans or
>   for the creation of lazy-init proxies only. For example, as
>   autodetected infrastructure bean in an XML application context
>   definition:

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator">
   <property name="customTargetSourceCreators">
     <list>
       <bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.target.LazyInitTargetSourceCreator"/>
     </list>
   </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="myLazyInitBean" class="mypackage.MyBeanClass" lazy-init="true">
   ...
 </bean>
```

If you find yourself doing this several times in an application context, this will save on configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Spring, but in Guice you would use a `Provider<ServiceB>`, so that when you were ready to use the service you'd go `provider.get().callMethodOnB(...)`.

This is, I believe, part of the JSR-330 spec, so it's possible there's an equivalent thing in Spring (I haven't used an up-to-date version of Spring for quite some time).

Comment: See now! If you're going to downvote, wouldn't it be polite to leave a note saying why?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [method injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-method-injection).
As a rule it's required to obtain a new instance of a singleton bean from a context, but it can be used in your case too.

Sample:

```
package org.test.lazy;

public abstract class ParentBean {
    public abstract LazyBean getLazy();
    public void lazyDoingSomething() {
        getLazy().doSomething();
    }
}
```

---

```
package org.test.lazy;

public class LazyBean {
   public void init() {
       System.out.println("Initialized");
   }
   public void doSomething() {
       System.out.println("Doing something");
   }
}
```

---

```
package org.test.lazy;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class LazyTest {

    @Autowired
    private ParentBean parentBean;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        parentBean.lazyDoingSomething();
        parentBean.lazyDoingSomething();
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
">
    <import resource="classpath:org/test/lazy/Lazy-context.xml"/>
    <bean id="parentBean" class="org.test.lazy.ParentBean">
        <lookup-method bean="lazyBean" name="getLazy"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
"
default-lazy-init="true">

    <bean id="lazyBean" class="org.test.lazy.LazyBean" init-method="init" />
</beans>
```

So you lazy bean will be initialized only once on demand.