# Instantiation of Bean through Factory method

Tags: spring

I have declared a bean which is instantiated via a factory method. The factory method invokes some remote services. So, the method has been declared to throw Exception.

The bean is correctly being instantiated when everything works fine. However, when the factory method throws exception, then everything starts going wrong. because my declared bean is referenced from another bean.

I want to set a default value, if the factory method throws Exception.

Part of my config file is as follows :

```
<bean id="Helper" class="com.test.Helper">
   <constructor-arg ref="myBean" />
</bean>
<bean id="myBean" class="com.test.Factory" factory-method="getBean" />
```

the getBean() method is as follows:

```
Factory {
      public static Bean getBean() throws Exception{
             //Invokes some Remote Services and does some processing
             ....
             ....
            //returns bean object
      }

  }
```

Please help me how I can solve this. I am not allowed to modify the factory method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If bean or factory method throws an exception during creation, the whole application context startup fails (I guess this is what you mean by "*everything starts going wrong*"). There is nothing you can do about it on the Spring side.

If you want to return some default value, simply catch the exception in your custom factory, log it and return that default. If you cannot modify the existing factory, consider `@Configuration` approach:

```
@Configuration
public SafeCfg {

    @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
    public Bean bean() {
        try {
            return Factory.getBean();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return //some default Bean
        }
    }

}
```

It works since Spring 3.0. Just place it somewhere so that the application context can pick it up.

But I doubt this is what you want. Even when the external system becomes available, you'll be still using the default, fallback value. Do you expect it to work like this? More advanced approach is to use lazy proxy (Spring has support for that: [Is there a spring lazy proxy factory in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391168)) and initialize it only when needed and refresh when broken.

Comment: My issue is I have to invoke that existing factory method. Is there any spring configuration like listener kind of thing which will take me to another method if factory method throws exception ?

Comment: why did you say that if the external system becomes available, then it will be still using the default value ? Do you mean by this, I won't get the value returned from Factory if it does not fire any exception ?

Comment: @Surya No, it means that if the system was unavailable and exception was thrown during startup, you'll still be using the default value until the application is restarted (unless your bean is created on demand), even if the system became avaialable in the meantime.

Comment: I got that worked..but why spring fires exception, if my default value is null; i.e. if the factory method returns null ?

Comment: @Surya: don't know, the API says it is valid since 2.0. If you need to return `null`, please file another question and post the stack trace. But a better idea - rather than `null` return some empty `Stub` object (*null object pattern*).

Comment: @Surya: sorry. just got it, it is not a problem with `FactoryBean` but with `@Bean` annotated method returning `null`. I don't think this is allowed.

Comment: but I haven't annotated the method with @Bean. I just use the xml file as my spring configuration.

Comment: @Surya: try also implementing `FactoryBean` with the code similar as above. The `null` should be acceptable there.

Comment: I have implemented the same way but just without the annotations. It works fine. but the problem comes if I keep my default value as null.